# JQuery: json to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var gallery = new TGallery([[{"image":{"updated_at":"2010-03-20T00:00:00Z","title":"dfgdfg","spam_reports":0,"by_profile_id":1,"comment_count":0,"id":1,"description":"htt","on_type":"profile","adult_reports":0,"on_id":1,"created_at":"2010-03-20T00:00:00Z"}]]);
```

Then in the TGallery class I would like to convert the json object to a js object.
thanks

without a plugin if is possible... :)

Comment: Teehee. Someone forgot that JSON *is* javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted isn't *quite* valid (missing a `}`), but if you can change the format a bit, no need for conversion, something like this:

```
var gallery = [{"image":{"updated_at":"2010-03-20T00:00:00Z","title":"dfgdfg","spam_reports":0,"by_profile_id":1,"comment_count":0,"id":1,"description":"htt","on_type":"profile","adult_reports":0,"on_id":1,"created_at":"2010-03-20T00:00:00Z"}}];
```

Changes here: added the closing brace, removed the extra `[]` wrapper and removed the `TGallery()` call.  Then you can loop though/access images like this:

```
$.each(gallery, function(i, o) {
    alert(o.image.updated_at);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

That is already a "JS object". Just try accessing the argument in TGallery and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You're already passing in a JavaScript object in that example. If you had a JSON string instead, you could do the following:

If you're using jQuery >= 1.4.1 you can use its built-in [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method to turn your JSON string into an object. Otherwise, you'll want to use the [library from JSON.org](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: I'm sure there's a really good reason not to, but what's wrong with good old eval?

Comment: @spender `eval` will execute the string as code exactly as written. Using a JSON parser will verify that the string conforms to the JSON format which protects your script from various security implications, which have been thoroughly documented around the web.

Comment: If the "JSON" is from a trusted source, eval() does not introduce any security holes, however I personally prefer to treat eval as evil all the time.